General Leibniz integral rule
Is there any version of the Leibniz integral rule for integration sets?
Suppose $z_j=Y_j + H_j$ if $j\neq1$, and $z_1=Y_1 + H_1  + t$, where $j=1, ..., n$.
Now suppose that $Y_j$ and $H_j$ have a smooth joint distribution $F(\alpha)$. And that the set with the maximum among all j s are: $\max_j=\{\alpha: z_j \geq z_j' \quad  \text{for all} \quad j' \neq j\}$.
The sum of all maximum j's are: $\text{Total} = \sum_j \left(\int_{\alpha \in Max_j} z_j dF(\alpha)\right)$.
How can I calculate the derivative of Total with respect to t? It will potentially change some maximums for combinations $\alpha$.

Please format it using Latex.
